# Can slurp be used as a direct replacement for lookup?

Tags: ansible

I have the following in a template file `foo.cfg.j2`:

```
nameserver dns1 {{ lookup('file','/etc/resolv.conf') | regex_search('\\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\b') }}:53
```

The problem is it gets the value from the local `/etc/resolv.conf`. I wanted to get the value from the target, I learned that I have to use `slurp`, but the second "problem" is that I need to register an variable in the task, and then pass it to the template file, like this:

```
tasks:
  - slurp:
      src: /etc/resolv.conf
    register: slurpfile
```

and the template file is now like this:

```
nameserver dns1 {{ slurpfile['content'] | b64decode | regex_search('\\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\b') }}:53
```

While this works, I feel a bit uneasy as the solution is split into two places: the task does something, and then the template file does the second part. Is there a remote version of `lookup` that is a direct replacement?

Comment: Have you considered using `set_fact:` in order to decouple the way the `dns1_ip` is acquired from the way the template is going to use it?

Comment: There is no such direct replacement. You can't expect any lookup plugin to provide you with the functionality of a module. [There are substantial differences](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#modules-and-plugins-what-is-the-difference).

Comment: @mdaniel yes, I have considered using `set_fact:` but I found that it also set a variable in task to be used in template. I do not see the conceptual difference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *slurp* I'd rather [*fetch*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#ansible-builtin-fetch-module-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes) the remote files

```yaml
  - fetch:
      src: /etc/resolv.conf
      dest: "{{ fetched_files }}"
```

,declare a variable, e.g.

```yaml
my_etc_recolv_conf: "{{ fetched_files }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/resolv.conf"
```

,and use it in the template

```yaml
nameserver dns1 {{ lookup('file', my_etc_recolv_conf) | ...
```